# conversion from double to byte array and vice versa

Tags: c#

i want to convert double array to byte array and byte array to double array

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;


namespace BitConversion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] Array = new double[] { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0 };
            byte[] byteArray = GetBytesAlt(Array);
            for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(byteArray[i]);
                Console.Write(",");

            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            double[] doubleArray = GetDoublesAlt(byteArray);
            for (int i = 0; i < doubleArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(doubleArray[i]);
                Console.Write(",");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// convert to bytes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="values"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static byte[] GetBytesAlt(double[] values)
        {
            /*var result = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(double)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(values, 0, result, 0, result.Length); 
            return result;*/

            return values.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();

            //return values.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray(); 

        }

        static double[] GetDoublesAlt(byte[] bytes)
        {
           /* var result = new double[bytes.Length / sizeof(double)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, result, 0, bytes.Length);
            return result;*/
            return Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length / sizeof(double)).Select(offset => BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, offset * sizeof(double))).ToArray(); 

        }
    }
}
```

with the convert approach the when bytes are converted back to the doubles 
the numbers are getting as 10.0,20.0, 30.0, 40.0.....

How to get back the same numbers?

I mean if the double entered is 10.0, 20.0 , 30.0 , 40.0
and i have get back the same number is 10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're saying you're getting the same numbers back, and you want to get the same numbers back? I tried your code, and indeed got the same numbers back. What is the problem?

Comment: Is the issue here simply `10` vs `10.0` ? If so, that's just a formatting thing. It is the same **number** either way. If you loop over `Array` you'll find that also, `Array` gives `"10,20,30,40,"`

Comment: i wanted to print the number as 10.0...

Comment: the entered number are 10.0,20.0,30.0,40.0 but i am getting as 10,20,30,40

Comment: @Raghav55 right; but that has nothing **whatsoever** to do with the `double <===> byte[]`, and everything to do with how you are writing them

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your program - if you slightly modify your program and print the original as well as round-tripped array, you will indeed see that you get the same out-put.
For example,

```
Original:       10.1,20.2,30,40,
Round-trip:     10.1,20.2,30,40,
```

Here's the slightly modified  code

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] Array = new double[] { 10.1, 20.2, 30.0, 40.0 };
            Console.Write("Original:\t");
            PrintArray(Array);

            byte[] byteArray = GetBytesAlt(Array);
            double[] doubleArray = GetDoublesAlt(byteArray);
            Console.Write("Round-trip:\t");
            PrintArray(doubleArray);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PrintArray(Double[] array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i]);
                Console.Write(",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

            // rest of methods are same
            ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the correct numbers, it is only in writing to the console that you are loosing your .0  the two numbers are equivalant. 10.0 and 10. This is what your doubleArray looks like before writing.

[image]

Try changing your Console.Write statement to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doubleArray.Length; i++)
    {
      //Since you are forcing the .0 you need to make sure you have enough #'s 
      //for the level of precision you need. It is actually better to use the 
      //system default since 10.0 and 10 are functionaly equivalent.

        Console.Write( doubleArray[i].ToString("##.0####")); 
        Console.Write(",");
    }
```

Comment: one more thing , which is the best way to the byte coversion var result = new byte[values.Length * sizeof(double)]; Buffer.BlockCopy(values, 0, result, 0, result.Length); return result;

Comment: @Raghav55 What are you asking, which is better?

Comment: the example which have poseted, using linq or the using the blockcopy

Comment: @Raghav55 They both appear to work correctly. It would depend on what you are trying to do and what and if any issues you run into and if they are both equally responsive.